# How to unit test mongotemplate functions

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mongotemplate

I want to write unit test for mongotemplate function calls. I am not sure how to write that, I have seen instances of integration test case only on web.

```java
public Class customerById(String id) {
        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
        return template.findOne(query, Class.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, just modify class name

```java
@Test
public void can_find_customer_by_customerId() {
    String id = someString(9);
    Customer Customer = mock(Customer.class);

    given(template.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id)), Customer.class)).willReturn(Customer);

    Customer actual = factory.customerById(id);

    assertEquals(actual, Customer);
}
```